# How to remove Guest user on Azure Active Directory?

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azureportal

I added a user with a directory role as a 'Guest'. I now want to remove. 
The Azure Portal user interface has a "Delete" option but it is grayed out without any explanation. I have tried through the "Find a User" screen, I have tried through the "Quick Overview Screen" and I have tried "Manage -> Users and Groups -> All Users". All the same thing, "Delete" is disabled with no explanation.

I have also tried through Powershell. I installed the AzureRM and Azure modules into Powershell. I access my Azure account and following multiple online docs (namely the Azure GitHub docs: https://github.com/Azure/azure-docs-powershell-azuread/blob/master/Azure%20AD%20Cmdlets/MSOnline/index.md) for accessing Azure AD I cannot connect.

I type  into Powershell:

```
$Msolcred = Get-credential
```

Which prompts for credentials, then following tutorials I try to use the cmdlet:

```
Connect-MsolService -Credential $MsolCred
```

But I receive the error:

```
Connect-MsolService : The term 'Connect-MsolService' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script fi
or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and
try again.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Add-AzureRmAccount -SubscriptionName 'SUBNAME'
Get-AzureRmADUser #Look up the user GUID
Remove-AzureRmADUser -UPNOrObjectId 'USER GUID'
```

To install this module you should run 'Install-Module AzureRM' (it will take some time)

Comment: Hi 4c74356b41, thanks for the reply. When I tried getting the user by their GUID I got this error: "Get-AzureRMADUser : Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."

Comment: When I go into Azure AD through the Azure Portal I see the account I made it with is marked with directory role of "User" however, once again, changing anything (to admin for instance) is disabled with no explanation.

Comment: well, you obviously don't have enough permissions for that

Comment: Do you know if I don't have permissions to change my role who would or how can I? It is a brand new account and I am the owner.

Comment: well, i'm not sure what is going on, but you obviously don't have permissions against the tenant, you need to use the account with global admin permissions on the tenant to grant yourself proper rights, or delete said user

Comment: Very odd indeed. I appreciate you taking the time to help. Perhaps there is some kind of glitch on this account in the way it propagated the Azure AD. I did not explicitly create it myself it was generated when I made my Azure account and then used it to create a Team Services project (which it then used as the basis of Team Services users).

Comment: so what role your account has in the tenant? there supposed to be an admin user anyway, can you look it up, do you know how to login with it?

Comment: I can't actually see my accounts role as tenant - When I choose "View My Permissions" it asks me to select a subscription - problem is I do not have one. The AD was made without one, as it wasn't required for making the Team Services account. Even trying to upgrade to the "Free Trial" subscription fails with an error "Sorry, we could not complete the operation. Please try again later or reload the web page". Looks like I am going to have wait the two weeks or so it will take for the back and forth email support with Azure.

Comment: looks like yes :(

Comment: You can't make this stuff up - submitting a support request/email is bugged for me as well. I submit it and it then doesn't confirm it was sent/appear in the "All Support Requests" tab. Sigh.

Comment: tweet them, they are pretty prompt to respond there, @AzureSupport